# Acknowledge the web api call before processing in Web Api C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a main web app which sends the alert to second application and the second application here needs to do more work, meanwhile main application will be waiting for the acknowledgment, hence once the second app receives the request, it should acknowledge by sending a flag and then continue its work.

In order to achieve that i am creating a new method and processing the data there and i am calling that new method using new thread and immediately returning the acknowledgement to main app.

Below is my code, am i following the right approach or is there a better way of doing it ?

```
    public bool Post([FromBody] string content)
    {            
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => AnotherMethod(content));
            thread.Start();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: If you want to achieve asyncronous messaging between apps, that's what message queues are for. There's [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), [Azure ServiceBus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-overview), and lots of other options. If you want to have a lot of the boilerplate set up for you in .NET, check out [MassTransit](https://masstransit-project.com/). You generally shouldn't be starting threads from your web applications to process work in the background. The app doing the background work shouldn't be a web app.

Comment: If its working fine with your application that is ok, but a better approach would be to implement a service bus (ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ) here, by which your applications can communicate properly and effectively, without depending on each others.

Comment: Don't create threads, use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `async` / `await`

```
public async Task<bool> Post([FromBody] string content)
{            
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
    {
        await AnotherMethod(content);
    }
    return true;
}
```

then your `AnotherMethod` must be `async` too